# Mac OS X Mojave problem in facebook chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, macos-mojave

I've updated my Mac to Mac OS X Mojave beta 10.14.1 and I'm having a problem of using Facebook and draw.io in Chrome. Both websites do not work I can't scroll down or chat. I have experienced some website and most are not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem has been solved after updating to the latest OS version.